# After uploading the Theme getting fatal error call to a member function error in Opencart version 2.3.0.2

Tags: opencart

After uploading the journal Theme I have seen this error in my admin panel or front-end panel.

Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on null in /home/kittosco/public_html/system/engine/front.php on line 45

I am using opencart version: 2.3.0.2